# How to move line of text below another?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having trouble moving one line of text below another. I have a feeling its something to do with the flexbox vertical align. I have also tried using `display: block` but to no avail. Please help, thank you.

The problem is the first section here:
https://jsfiddle.net/sqeeux47/

HTML

```
<section id="section1">
    <h1 id="section1heading">Welcome to our multicultural society.</h1>
    <h4 id="section1paragraph">Come worship with us.</h4>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#section1 {
    background-image: url(" http://i300.photobucket.com/...");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    background-position:center;
    width:100%;
    height:606px;
    text-align:center;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your efforts first, so we can help you..

Comment: It seems the link isnt working, please hang on

Comment: I suggest you to add your code here on stackoverflow, since external links might die in the future..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sqeeux47/ This should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one line to the parent container:

```
#section1 { flex-direction: column; }
```

OR

```
#section1 { flex-wrap: wrap; }
```

When you create a flex container (by declaring `display: flex` on an element), several default rules go into effect. Two of these rules are `flex-direction: row` and `flex-wrap: nowrap`.

This means that flex items will align horizontally on a single line, which is the issue you are facing.

In order to alter this behavior, you could change the `flex-direction` or allow flex items to wrap.